# Intranet communication issue in ECS with Route53 in private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-route53, amazon-ecs, service-discovery

I have hosted our applications on ECS Cluster (EC2 Mode) in a private subnet. I am facing problem with inter-service communication.

- I have set task networking mode as bridge.
- Depending on Route53 private hosted zone for service discovery.
- The services are getting registered under Route53 with **SRV** record type.
- Using . for pointing to our hosted service. For example, I have hosted redis container with namespace "local" and service name as "redisdb" then referring that service in application as "redisdb.local"

But I am getting an error in our application saying: "Name or Service not known". I have also tried with AWSVPC mode with **A** record type. But still I am facing same issue.

Am I missing anything here? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

hmm, finally the issue was resolved by enabling the dns hostname

Comment: How did you enable the DNS Hostname?
Did you add a new A Record into Route53 Private Zone?